# Open TIN DEM File format

Tags: dem, file-formats, tin

Anyone know a TIN DEM file format commonly used?

In the context of a TIN DEM generator project, I am searching for a file format to save the TIN generated.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is UGRID:
https://github.com/ugrid-conventions/ugrid-conventions

As the format is supported by MDAL (https://github.com/lutraconsulting/MDAL/blob/master/mdal/frmts/mdal_3di.cpp) which means you can visualise your mesh directly in QGIS.

Comment: +1 Also since only `Ugrid` format supports projection in QGIS.

Comment: since `Ugrid` is preferred, it probably would be a good idea to set it as the default format in QGIS. For example the default output format for `TIN Mesh Creation` Algorithm.
Commenting here since I know this functionality is developed by Lutra